# Replace the city text field by a dropdown of cities for a specific country in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

The existing list of countries is excellent, but we need to select Saudi Arabia in particular and show it another list with the names of the main cities such as Riyadh, Jeddah, etc. The last option is another, and if he selects another, a text box will appear to write the name of the city or region in which it is located.

I try this, Its work with me when select Saudi Arabia, i can show list of cities, but I could not do if he selects another, a text box will appear to write the name of the city or region in which it is located.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'customize_checkout_city_field' );
function customize_checkout_city_field( $address_fields ) {
global $woocommerce;
if ($woocommerce->customer->get_country() == 'SA') {    

                $towns_cities_arr = array(
            '0' => __('Select City', 'my_theme_slug'),
                    'Abhā' => 'Abhā',
                    'Abqaiq' => 'Abqaiq',
                    'Al-Baḥah' => 'Al-Baḥah',
                    'Al-Dammām' => 'Al-Dammām',
                    'Al-Hufūf' => 'Al-Hufūf',
                    'Al-Jawf' => 'Al-Jawf',
                    'Al-Kharj' => 'Al-Kharj',
                    'Al-Khubar' => 'Al-Khubar',
                    'Al-Qaṭīf' => 'Al-Qaṭīf',
                    'Al-Ṭaʾif' => 'Al-Ṭaʾif',
                    'ʿArʿar' => 'ʿArʿar',
                    'Buraydah' => 'Buraydah',
                    'Dhahran' => 'Dhahran',
                    'Ḥāʾil' => 'Ḥāʾil',
                    'Jiddah' => 'Jiddah',
                    'Jīzān' => 'Jīzān',
                    'Khamīs Mushayt' => 'Khamīs Mushayt',
                    'King Khalīd Military City' => 'King Khalīd Military City',
                    'Mecca' => 'Mecca',
                    'Medina' => 'Medina',
                    'Najrān' => 'Najrān',
                    'Ras Tanura' => 'Ras Tanura',
                    'Riyadh' => 'Riyadh',
                    'Sakākā' => 'Sakākā',
                    'Tabūk' => 'Tabūk',
                    'Yanbuʿ' => 'Yanbuʿ',
                    'Other' => 'Other',
                );
                $address_fields['city']['type'] = 'select';
                $address_fields['city']['class'] = array('update_totals_on_change');

                $address_fields['city']['label'] = __('City', 'my_theme_slug'); 

                $address_fields['city']['options'] = $towns_cities_arr;
} else {
                $address_fields['city']['type'] = 'text';
}   
                return $address_fields;         
}
```

Comment: you are only selling to Saudi Arabia right?

Comment: @kashalo only Saudi Arabia and UEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Updated** *(Additional city text field when "Others" is the selected value from the dropdown)*

The following code *(**jQuery** powered)* will replace the city text field by a custom dropdown of cities **for a specific country only** and for this specific country, if the city selected value is "Others", **an additional text field will appear under the cities dropdown**, where customer can enter manually a different city.

The code works for shipping and billing fields independently.

When "Others" is selected for the defined country, the two last functions will:

- Validate that the city additional field is filled,
- Save the city value as billing or shipping city value.

The code:

```
// HERE are is the array of cities for Saudi Arabia (SA)
function get_cities_options(){
    $domain = 'woocommerce'; // The domain text slug

    return array(
        ''          => __('Select a city', $domain),
        'Abhā'      => 'Abhā',      'Abqaiq'    => 'Abqaiq',
        'Al-Baḥah'  => 'Al-Baḥah',  'Al-Dammām' => 'Al-Dammām',
        'Al-Hufūf'  => 'Al-Hufūf',  'Al-Jawf'   => 'Al-Jawf',
        'Al-Kharj'  => 'Al-Kharj',  'Al-Khubar' => 'Al-Khubar',
        'Al-Qaṭīf'  => 'Al-Qaṭīf',  'Al-Ṭaʾif'  => 'Al-Ṭaʾif',
        'ʿArʿar'    => 'ʿArʿar',    'Buraydah'  => 'Buraydah',
        'Dhahran'   => 'Dhahran',   'Ḥāʾil'     => 'Ḥāʾil',
        'Jiddah'    => 'Jiddah','Jīzān'     => 'Jīzān',
        'Khamīs Mushayt'            => 'Khamīs Mushayt',
        'King Khalīd Military City' => 'King Khalīd Military City',
        'Mecca'     => 'Mecca',     'Medina'    => 'Medina',
        'Najrān'    => 'Najrān',    'Ras Tanura'=> 'Ras Tanura',
        'Riyadh'    => 'Riyadh',    'Sakākā'    => 'Sakākā',
        'Tabūk'     => 'Tabūk',     'Yanbuʿ'    => 'Yanbuʿ',
        'Other'     => __('Other cities (not listed)', $domain),
    );
}

// add an additional field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'additional_checkout_city_field' );
function additional_checkout_city_field( $fields ) {
    // Inline CSS To hide the fields on start
    ?><style> #billing_city2_field.hidden, #shipping_city2_field.hidden {display:none;}</style><?php

    $fields['billing']['billing_city2'] = array(
        'placeholder'   => _x('Other city', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'priority'  => 75,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide hidden'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city2'] = array(
        'placeholder'   => _x('Other city', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => false,
        'priority'  => 75,
        'class'     => array('form-row-wide hidden'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    return $fields;
}

// Add checkout custom select fields
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_city_field', 20, 1 );
function custom_checkout_city_field() {
    // Only checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ):

    $country = 'SA'; //  <=== <=== The country code

    $b_city  = 'billing_city';
    $s_city  = 'shipping_city';
    $billing_city_compo    = 'name="'.$b_city.'" id="'.$b_city.'"';
    $shipping_city_compo   = 'name="'.$s_city.'" id="'.$s_city.'"';
    $end_of_field          = ' autocomplete="address-level2" value="">';
    $billing_text_field    = '<input type="text" class="input-text" ' . $billing_city_compo  . $end_of_field;
    $shipping_text_field   = '<input type="text" class="input-text" ' . $shipping_city_compo . $end_of_field;
    $billing_select_field  = '<select ' . $billing_city_compo  . $end_of_field;
    $shipping_select_field = '<select ' . $shipping_city_compo . $end_of_field;

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var a   = <?php echo json_encode( get_cities_options() ); ?>,           fc = 'form.checkout',
            b   = 'billing',                s   = 'shipping',               ci = '_city2',
            bc  = '<?php echo $b_city; ?>', sc = '<?php echo $s_city; ?>',  co = '_country',
            bci = '#'+bc,                   sci = '#'+sc,                   fi = '_field',
            btf = '<?php echo $billing_text_field; ?>',     stf = '<?php echo $shipping_text_field; ?>',
            bsf = '<?php echo $billing_select_field; ?>',   ssf = '<?php echo $shipping_select_field; ?>',
            cc  = '<?php echo $country; ?>';

        // Utility function that fill dynamically the select field options
        function dynamicSelectOptions( type ){
            var select = (type == b) ? bsf : ssf,
                fvalue = (type == b) ? $(bci).val() : $(sci).val();


            $.each( a, function( key, value ){
                selected = ( fvalue == key ) ? ' selected' : '';
                selected = ( ( fvalue == '' || fvalue == undefined ) && key == '' ) ? ' selected' : selected;
                select += '<option value="'+key+'"'+selected+'>'+value+'</option>';
            });
            select += '</select>';

            if ( type == b ) 
                $(bci).replaceWith(select);
            else 
                $(sci).replaceWith(select);
        }

        // Utility function that will show / hide the "country2" additional text field
        function showHideCity2( type, city ){
            var field   = (type == b) ? bci : sci,
                country = $('#'+type+co).val();

            if( country == cc && city == 'Other' && $('#'+type+ci+fi).hasClass('hidden') ){
                $('#'+type+ci+fi).removeClass('hidden');
            } else if( country != cc || ( city != 'Other' && ! $('#'+type+ci+fi).hasClass('hidden') ) ) {
                $('#'+type+ci+fi).addClass('hidden');
                if( country != cc && city == 'Other' ){
                    $(field).val('');
                }
            }
        }

        // On billing country change
        $(fc).on('change', '#'+b+co, function(){
            var bcv = $(bci).val();
            if($(this).val() == cc){
                if( $(bci).attr('type') == 'text' ){
                    dynamicSelectOptions(b);
                    showHideCity2( b, $(bci).val() );
                }
            } else {
                if( $(bci).attr('type') != 'text' ){
                    $(bci).replaceWith(btf);
                    $(bci).val(bcv);
                    showHideCity2( b, $(bci).val() );
                }
            }
        });

        // On shipping country change
        $(fc).on('change', '#'+s+co, function(){
            var scv = $(sc).val();
            if($(this).val() == cc){
                if( $(sci).attr('type') == 'text' ){
                    dynamicSelectOptions(s);
                    showHideCity2( s, $(sci).val() );
                }
            } else {
                if( $(sci).attr('type') != 'text' ){
                    $(sci).replaceWith(stf);
                    $(sci).val(scv);
                    showHideCity2( s, $(sci).val() );
                }
            }
        });

        // On billing city change
        $(fc).on('change', bci, function(){
            showHideCity2( b, $(this).val() );
        });

        // On shipping city change
        $(fc).on('change', sci, function(){
            showHideCity2( s, $(this).val() );
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}

// Check  for city 2 fields if billing or/and shipping city fields is "Other"
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'cbi_cf_process');
function cbi_cf_process() {
    // Check billing city 2 field
    if( isset($_POST['billing_city2']) && empty($_POST['billing_city2']) && $_POST['billing_city'] == 'Other' ){
        wc_add_notice( __( "Please fill in billing city field" ), "error" );
    }

    // Updating shipping city 2 field
    if( isset($_POST['shipping_city2']) && empty($_POST['shipping_city2']) && $_POST['shipping_city'] == 'Other' ){
        wc_add_notice( __( "Please fill in shipping city field" ), "error" );
    }
}

// Updating billing and shipping city fields when using "Other"
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'update_order_city_field', 30, 2 );
function update_order_city_field( $order, $posted_data ) {
    // Updating billing city from 'billing_city2'
    if( isset($_POST['billing_city2']) && ! empty($_POST['billing_city2']) && $_POST['billing_city'] == 'Other' ){
        $order->set_billing_city(sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_city2'] ) );
    }

    // Updating shipping city
    if( isset($_POST['shipping_city2']) && ! empty($_POST['shipping_city2']) && $_POST['shipping_city'] == 'Other' ){
        $order->set_shipping_city(sanitize_text_field( $_POST['shipping_city'] ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

> Please Remember that a customer can be in a foreign country outside Soudi Arabia (billing country) and buy something that will be shipped in Soudi Arabia (shipping country).

Comment: thank you,, can you see my array ,, if i select other ,, its must add new text field to add new city not found in array, and this you are no add it

Comment: If you select Saudi Arabia, and you specify the city (other) I want to show a text field, type the name of the new city, That not found in dropdown of cities

Comment: @abukotshalmallahi I have updated the answer, with an additional city text field when "Others" is the selected value from the dropdown.

Comment: thank you,, but there are problem when save it fro WordPress theme editor, see ( http://prntscr.com/l1iwva )

Comment: @abukotshalmallahi The code need to be added in your theme's function.php file. There is no problems with this answer code as it's fully tested and works. You can also use the [**Code Snippets** plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) that woocommerce recommend. Using the theme editor is not recommended. You should use an external editor linked to your FTP software.

Comment: Nice Solution, bus is it possible to filter the city based on State?, to use it for shipping purposes in UAE